# Countdown timer on SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, .net, simplemodal

Saw a related post here on auto-close SimpleModal after n seconds (works great), but I would like to also display a countdown timer within the modal content. For reference here was the auto-close solution. Any thoughts?

```
$.modal('<div>HELLO</div>', {
overlayClose: true,
onShow: function() {
    var timer;
    $('#simplemodal-container').bind({
        mouseenter: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            timer = setTimeout($.modal.close, 1500);
        }
    })
    .trigger('mouseleave');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Having this in the onShow parameter worked for me:

```
onShow: function (dialog) {
   var modal = this;
   $('.messageTimeout', dialog.data[0]).append(message3);
   countdow = 59;
   setInterval(function() {
      $('.messageTimeout', dialog.data[0]).html('You will be logged out in ' + countdow + ' seconds if you do not take any action.');
      countdow -= 1;
   },1000);
}
```